# Modify URL Parameters from a list menu

Tags: jquery, url, parameters

i want to modify the url parameters from a nav menu 
for example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="example.com/int/eng/custom-page-1"></li>
    <li><a href="example.com/ch/ger/custom-page-2"></li>
    <li><a href="example.com/int/eng/custom-page-3"></li>
</ul>
```

into this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="example.com/int/eng/custom-page-1"></li>
    <li><a href="example.com/custom-page-2"></li>
    <li><a href="example.com/custom-page-3"></li>
</ul>
```

i want to "delete" starting at the second link the two parameters /xxx/xxx/ (maximum are three characters)
custom-page means the names are not static and can be named everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
$('ul li:not(:first-child)').each(function () {
    $(this).find('a').attr('href', function (_, href) {
        return href.replace(/\/.+\//, "/");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uj77b75f/)

Answer (score -1):

check this solution

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").attr("href","example.com/custom-page-2");
$("ul li:nth-child(3)").attr("href","example.com/custom-page-3");
```